# SQL - Consulta valor max de un group by de tres columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server, servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer es que la consulta me devuelta del valor de la columna **numeroSolicitud** de un grupo de datos de la columna **secuencialGarantia** pero dependiendo del valor máximo de **deudaInicial**.

Resultado deseado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hice es:

```
SELECT numeroSolicitud, secuencialGarantia, max(deudaInicial) FROM #temp_Garantias 
GROUP BY secuencialGarantia
```

Me devuelve el error:

*La columna '#temp_Garantias.numeroSolicitud' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.*

Espero me hayan entendido lo que necesito que me ayuden, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY secuencialGarantia
                              ORDER BY deudaInicial DESC) RN
    FROM #temp_Garantias
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Gracias una forma mas fácil de hacer y entender lo que necesito, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que indica el error es que la columna `numeroSolicitud` no esta dentro de la clausula `GROUP BY` o por lo menos contenida dentro de una funcion de agregado (por ejemplo la funcion MAX que utilizas es una funcion de agregado).

Lo que debes hacer es agregar a la clausula `GROUP BY` el nombre de la columna `numeroSolicitud`.

Quedaria de esta forma:

```
SELECT numeroSolicitud, secuencialGarantia, max(deudaInicial) FROM #temp_Garantias 
GROUP BY numeroSolicitud, secuencialGarantia
```

***Actualizando***:

Por lo que colocas en tu edicion, necesitas la deuda maxima con el numero de solicitud minimo, si es asi intenta con este query.

```
SELECT MIN(numeroSolicitud), secuencialGarantia, max(deudaInicial) FROM #temp_Garantias 
GROUP BY secuencialGarantia
```

Te dejo unas referencias:

- [Group By](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Funciones agregadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta que agrupes. Para obtener el valor del campo `numeroSolicitud` que se corresponde con la mayor `deudaInicial`, lo que puedes hacer es imitar los resultados a 1 fila con la clausula `top 1` y ordenar por `deudaInicial` de manera descendente.

La consulta sería como la que sigue:

```
select top 1 numeroSolicitud, secuencialGarantia, deudaInicial
  from #temp_Garantias 
 where secuencialGarantia = 42
 order by deudaInicial desc;
```

He escrito esta otra para demostrar el resultado:

```
with
Garantias as (
select 925866 numeroSolicitud, 5 secuencialGarantia, 19000.0 deudaInicial
union all select 929472, 42, 3000
union all select 924842, 42, 7000
union all select 924988, 42, 29000
union all select 926715, 42, 8000
union all select 923169, 45, 23100
union all select 927939, 47, 50000
)
select top 1 numeroSolicitud, secuencialGarantia, deudaInicial
  from Garantias
 where secuencialGarantia = 42
 order by deudaInicial desc;
```

que devuelve:

```
numeroSolicitud secuencialGarantia deudaInicial
--------------- ------------------ --------------
924988          42                 29000.0

(1 row affected)
```

que es el dato que buscas.

Comment: muy bien explicado, eso es cuando se tiene el secuencialGarantia, pero en el caso de que tenga que recorrer toda la tabla, como se lo haría o es necesario utilizar un cursor, saludos

Comment: No es necesario un cursor. La consulta que te dí entrega exactamente el resultado que pides en tu pregunta. Nada más que hacer. Ya si el motor recorre toda la tabla o lo que haga para entregar el resultado, no es _nuestro problema_, esos son detalles de implementación que cada motor resuelve a su manera.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes SQL Server 2008 o superior podrías generar por medio de `ROW_NUMBER()` un numerador de fila, particionando el mismo por `secuencialGarantia` y ordenando por `deudaInicial` descendente, lo cual debería iniciar este número en 1 justamente en los casos dónde la Deuda es mayor.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (SELECT    numeroSolicitud, 
            secuencialGarantia, 
            deudaInicial,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY secuencialGarantia, ORDER BY deudaInicial DESC) AS RN
            FROM #temp_Garantias
    ) T
    WHERE RN = 1
```

Ver documentación de [SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Excelente amigo mil gracias me funciono tal como yo quería, saludos